# Automating config file changes for developers

Tags: powershell, automation, continuous-integration, chef-infra, continuous-deployment

I've been working with Chef and powershell to set up some type of automation in my company.

I've written some Chef recipes to automation package install and config changes. I've digested much of the material on the internet about automation in this respect.

On thing I'm struggling to come up with answer for is how to automate the changes to configuration files so that developers can make config changes to the system on their own.

I support a database application. We have a prod environment and 6-8 environments each in dev, test, and stage.

I will use a web.config file as an example.

I regularly will get request just to change 3 lines in the web.config, then a later request to change it back.

I want to empower the developer to make these changes on their own, but unsure how to set up an environment where this can be done.

I'm fairly familiar with chef, I suspect this would be a good tool to make this happen.

Put the files in a repository and develop a ci/cd pipeline to push out changes.

My issue is I'm unsure how to implement.

I'm unsure how to represent multiple development environments (Stage01, stage01, dev01, dev02, test01, test02, etc...) in the repository to make sure the changes get pushed out the the correct environment.

I also need to make it completely obvious to the developer which environment they are making changes to.

I can supply any additional details if needed.

I really just need to be pointed to an example, or I'm open to any other solutions that don't involve chef.

I have many tools available to me just unsure the best path forward.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to achieve it, but most of them will take advantage based on the chef [environment](https://docs.chef.io/environments.html#cookbook-pinning) - by using environment file or databag which has a key for each chef environment name (that is `node.chef_environment`).

when using an environment file, node attributes can be [overriden as json](https://docs.chef.io/environments.html#json) (see [attribute precedance](https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html#attribute-persistence)).

then configure the ci\cd pipeline to update chef server and execute chef-client upon changes to chef files (environment and\or databag files, etc.)